# losing classified values when converting from .tif to .asc (for Maxent)

Tags: arcgis-pro, classification, ascii, maxent

I have 10 aspect values in a .tif generated by ArcGIS from a DEM file. When I convert to .asc (necessary for Maxent) it becomes a single value arc from -1 to 360(m). I need to use this as a categorical file for my species distribution model, so my query is; is there a way to get Arc to 'hold' the 10 categories, as obviously 361 is too many!
I have tried exporting using renderer and force RGB but ended up with a 3 band file which did not have hold the values in any way. I can use symbology to put the classes on the .asc file, but this doesn't save on the file and it will revert back to -1 to 360.
Essentially, I am looking for a single band .asc file with 10 classes. (I have this in .tif format, but this is no good for Maxent).